# tikz: distance corresponding to below/above

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0.0, 0.0);
  \coordinate (B) at (-5.0, 5.0);
  \draw[] (A) -- (B) node [midway, below, sloped](textnode1){line};
  \draw[red, ->,
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={arc}, text align=center, reverse path,
    text effects/.cd,
      text along path,
      every character/.style={ yshift=0.5ex}}}] (A) arc (0:90:5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What `yshift` should I provide for the arc to be sure that it is the same as `above`/`below` used for the line?

Comment: `\draw[red, ->] (A) arc (0:90:5) node [midway, above, sloped]{arc};` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen from other question, I guess that you want a longer text than "arc" and it needs to follow the path. You can individually place the letters above or below the path. Like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0.0, 0.0);
  \coordinate (B) at (-5.0, 5.0);
  \draw[] (A) -- (B) node [midway, below, sloped](textnode1){line};
  \draw[red, ->,
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={arc}, text align=center, reverse path,
    text effects/.cd,
      text along path,
      every character/.style={below}}}] (A) arc (0:90:5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Line and arc with text]

`below`/`above` does not correspond to a specific shift, but changes the anchor of the node. The node moves because it has a size (`inner sep` is initially .3333em).

Answer (score 2):

Your image can be drawn much simpler. By use of Ti*k*Z libraries `arrows.meta` for arrows) and `quotes` (for edge labels). Label distances from edge is determined by `inner sep` of quotes. Default value is 3pt but with style `every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep=... , sloped}` you can change to desired amount:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep=1pt, sloped}
                        ]
\coordinate (A) at (0.0, 0.0);
\coordinate (B) at (-5.0, 5.0);
%
\draw   (A) to ["line" sloped] (B);
\draw[red, -{Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 4]}] 
        (A) to ["arc" sloped, bend right=45] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]